# primeNg p-RadioButton value not changing html

Tags: html, angular, radio-button, primeng

I have the following radiobuttons:

```
     <div class="nextgen-goal-overall-radiobuttons pull-left">
       <label class="nextgen-input-label">Overall Goal</label>
         <div class="radio-button-item pull-left" *ngFor="let goalType of goalTypesRadioButton">
          <p-radioButton  class="nextgen-radio-button" name="{{goalType.id}}" value="{{goalType.id}}" label="{{goalType.description}}" [(ngModel)]="selectedGoalTypeId"></p-radioButton>
         </div>
     </div>
```

When I click on any radio button the `selectedGoalTypeId` is updated with the corresponding value.

My problem here is that on my `HTML` I have the following conditional `divs`:

```
  <div class="nextgen-input-container nextgen-goal-input pull-left">
          <span *ngIf="selectedGoalTypeId === 1" class="goals-currency-icon">{{currencyFormat}}</span>
        <label class="nextgen-input-label nextgen-target-group-label">{{selectedGoalTypeId}}</label>
        <input class="nextgen-input" [class.nextgen-input-budget] = "selectedGoalTypeId === 1" type="number" pInputText placeholder="">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="selectedGoalTypeId === 3" class="nextgen-goal-frequency-dropdown pull-left">
        <label class="nextgen-input-label nextgen-target-group-label">Frequency</label>
        <p-dropdown [showTransitionOptions]="'0ms'" [hideTransitionOptions]="'0ms'" dropdownIcon="fa fa-angle-down" class= "nextgen-dropdown" [options]="FrequencyLookup" [(ngModel)]="selectedFrequency" value="selectedFrequency"></p-dropdown>
      </div>
```

Asking if `selectedGoalTypeId` is 1 or 3 it shows some divs or not.

The problem here is that the `selectedGoalTypeId` is updated correctly. I put some label on the `HTML` to check. But the divs are not changed according to the conditions it always displays the same despite of the value of `selectedGoalTypeId`. What I'm missing here?

Comment: Do the types of `goalType.id` and `selectedGoalTypeId` match?

Answer (score 1):

In `p-radioButton` change `value="{{goalType.id}}"` to `[value]="goalType.id"`

And I suppose that `*ngIf="selectedGoalTypeId === 1"` should be placed on the upper div than on the span

Posted the solution [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ax8frn)

PS : I guess `goalType.id` and `selectedGoalTypeId` are both `number`

Comment: I put == instead of === and worked your comment made me realize that the problem was there thanks a lot!

Comment: You should align types of `goalType.id` and `selectedGoalTypeId` and still use `===` and properly bind the `value` property of the radio button like explained above